# WINXP/AD GPO: Allow non-admin user to log off existing locked session

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, group-policy, user-accounts

I'm looking to create a policy that would allow
non-administrator users the ability to log off other non-administrators who
have left and have a locked screen. I really don't want to give the users
administrator access on the computers. Also, I'm also looking to apply this
to a restricted set of computers - not all computers in the domain.

There's something that I can do to obtain this?

Comment: After a long period of our users calling I.T. to have us unlock locked workstations, they started to realize that they could hit the power button to shutdown the PC, then power it back up.  End result is the same, with only a few minutes wait for bootup.

Comment: this is the "solution" I gave to the user who complained about it (who is the CEO of the company), but it don't seems very professional... and the computer takes too much to boot, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We handle this by not allowing shared workstations to be locked. If a user gets up from a shared workstation, he or she has to log out while it is unattended precisely to prevent this.

You can easily configure this option in GPO and apply it only to an OU that has that shared machines in it.

Comment: seems interesting, so if I could restrict to certain computers to don't lock even when screensaver comes up, and to shutdown after certain time unused, it would do the job.